# Cancel asynchronous calls

Tags: java, multithreading, future

We need to implement a feature that allows us to cancel a future job. Given that this job is doing DB calls and we need to rollback\cleanup any updates made before cancel was fired.

This is what I have tried, but "Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()" always return false:

```
 ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
 final Future future = executor.submit(new Callable() {
  @Override
  public Boolean call() throws Exception {

    // Do Some DB calls

    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     // Will need to roll back          
      throw new InterruptedException();
    }
    return true;
  }
 });

 executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    future.cancel(true);
  }
 }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Is this the right approach to achieve  our target? And how to know if the job was cancelled in order to cancel\roll back changes?

Comment: Are you sure your cancel task has run before the DB job finishes?

Comment: Some of these calls can take very long time to complete in this case the thread stays in the pool blocking other jobs from starting. we wants to make users able to cancel the whole job if it was taking too much time

Answer (score 1):

First it seems the thread pool is not creating new thread for you so your cancel task will get called only after the DB task finishes. So I changed the pool size in yours example to `2` and it worked.

Comment: The `InterruptedException` is only thrown if you sleep. If you do not sleep then checking the flag is correct as the exception will not be thrown. Look at the reasons why `Thread.stop()` was deprecated for an understanding why arbitrary statements do not just throw exceptions. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you complete the database calls before the second task gets a chance to run. When you have only a single executor it is possible that it does not schedule time for the second scheduled task before the first completes. This following snippet does get interrupted:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        ScheduledExecutorService runner = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
        // If this is 1 then this will never be interrupted.

        final Future f = runner.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Calling");
                while (! Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    ;
                }
                System.out.println("Interrupted");
                return true;
            }
        });

        runner.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Interrupting");
                f.cancel(true);
            }
        }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```